# Drop a request Using C-icap

Tags: c, icap

I am using the open source `c-icap` for modifying HTTP transaction, between a client and a server.

http://www.firefly.kutc.kansai-u.ac.jp/~k843966/c-icap/doc/structci__service__module.html

Is it possible to drop a request completely? I want to be able to stop a request from ever getting to the server. I know it is possible to send a customized response using.

```
int     ci_http_response_create (ci_request_t *req, int has_reshdr, int has_body)
```

I want to be able to just drop the request completely.

Comment: I am not looking for a software recommendation. Perhaps i should have been more clear. I am asking if there is a way of doing something like this with c-icap.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. I retracted my CV

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. It turns out that if I use ci_http_response_create(), without adding any header's the request gets blocked from getting to the server.